# Laravel Eloquent select in with empty

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

**my relation in User Model**

```
public function fullName()
{
    return $this->hasOne(UserProfile::class,'user_id','id')->where('slug', '=', 'full_name');
}

$user = User::query()with('fullName:slug')->get();
```

my result  :

```
'full_name' => null
```

Comment: What is your db data?

Comment: mysql => with('fullName') result =>  "full_name": {
"id": 1,
"user_id": 2,
"slug": "full_name",
"data": "حسین دانش asd aگلستان",
"expired_at": null,
"deleted_at": null,
"created_at": "2020-12-22T17:07:15.000000Z",
"updated_at": "2020-12-22T18:11:06.000000Z"
}

Comment: "When using this feature, you should always include the `id` column **AND** any relevant foreign key columns in the list of columns you wish to retrieve." https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-specific-columns

Comment: ok, how to select data ? (one)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to see the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-specific-columns)

When using this feature, you should always include the id column and any relevant foreign key columns in the list of columns you wish to retrieve.

```
$user = User::query()->with('fullName:id,slug')->get();
```